# Putting a dot underneath a navbar link CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a single dot under my active link in the navbar as showin in picture:
[image: Required design]

So far I have tried this:

```
.active-page {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #8edafa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #8edafa;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}
```

This gets me the following result:
[image]

How do I get that dot as shown in the first image?

Comment: Please include the HTML that goes with this CSS (Preferably in a functional snippet)

Comment: You should use pseudo elements like `.active-page::before` with `position: absolute`  which are easlier to style and position.

Comment: How is that long line beneath all the elements created, sized and positioned?

Comment: Border bottom and bottom padding as shown in the css

Answer (score 0):

A border wouldn't help you in that case.

You can use a pseudo element instead.
You have to use `position: absolute;` for the dot (.active-page::after), and `position: relative;` for the parent (.active-page)

Like:

```
.active-page {
  position: relative;
  // ...
}

.active-page::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  // ...
}
```